# How to pass a string to a function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to give a string parameter to a function

```
function test(p)
{
}

...innerHTML = '<div onclick="test(p)"><div>';
```

That does not work how to do it?

Comment: And why do you want to do that, wouldn't it be better to create an actual element with `createElement` and add an actual event handler with `addEventListener` ?

Comment: innerHTML = '<div onclick="test(\'p\')"><div>'; should work

Comment: Try with `innerHTML = '<div onclick="test('p')"><div>'; `

Comment: don't strings have to get marked up with "string"?

Comment: @TheFrenchPlaysHdMicraftn what do you mean?

Comment: user2415266 thanks that works perfect ;)

Comment: @TheFrenchPlaysHdMicraftn No, you can use `"` or `'` in JS.

Comment: if the answers would alsways appear so fast ;)))

Comment: And just to emphasis this again, you're doing it wrong -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/04dcf4dy/

Comment: Please rename the title of this question, since the title doesn't describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, if you have a single quotation marks/ double quotation marks issue you need to use the `\'` syntax (adding a `\` sign before a special character, like `\'` or `\"`).

```html
<html>
<body onload="onPageLoad()"> 
<script>
 function onPageLoad()
 {
  var testString = "This is the test text...";
  
  var divElement = document.createElement('div');
  
  divElement.innerHTML = '<h1 onclick="onClickFunc(\''+ testString + '\')">Click Me!</h1>';
  
  document.body.appendChild(divElement);
 } 

 function onClickFunc(str)
 {
  alert(str);
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `p` as a variable not a string. Here, `p` is not defined so error is coming. Give it as string.

**Try this:**

```
function test(p)
{
}

...innerHTML = '<div onclick=test("p")>ABC</div>';
```

**or**

```
function test(p)
{
}

...innerHTML = '<div onclick="test(\'p\')">ABC</div>';
```

Comment: your first example won't work, since onclick itself need to have quotation mark (onclick="...")

Comment: Quotation marks on events are optional. I tested it yesterday and it worked. Give it a try.